# Totalcensus api returns a data table with columns but 0 rows?

Tags: r, census

Is the Totalcensus library defunct?  I try the below call, follow the prompts to accept the downloaded data, and there's no errors but an empty data table is returned in R.

```
  library(totalcensus)

## ---------------------------------- totalcensus API call -----------------------------------------

set_path_to_census("X:/my_folder")

zip_acs5_2016 <- read_acs5year(
    year = 2016,
    states = "WI",
    geo_headers = "ZCTA5",
    table_contents = c(
        "white = B02001_002",
        "black = B02001_003",
        "asian = B02001_005"
    ),
    summary_level = "860"
)
```

Comment: Without some restrictions `read_acs5year(year = 2016, states = "WI")` returns a lot of data. I think, at least one of your arguments `geo_headers`, `table_contents` or `summary_level` does not work as expected.